# Python code to load json data into database SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have created a database using SQLAlchemy which column names business_id , useful.

```
class Review(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rev'
    id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    business_id = Column(String(50))
    useful = Column(Integer)
    # initial_rating=Column(Integer)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlalchemy_try.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Now i have a json file and i want to load the business id and useful present in json file into this database.I have opened the json file but dont know how to load it in this database:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy_declarative import  Base, Review

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlalchemy_try.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = DBSession()
with open('rev.json') as f:
    data=f.read()
    jsondata=json.loads(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suppose something like this:

```
r = Review(int(jsondata['id']), jsondata['business_id'], int(jsondata['useful']))
session.add(r)
```

In the end, add `session.commit()`.

Comment: It gives an error:                                                                      r= Review(jsondata['business_id'])
    KeyError: 'business_id'
[Finished in 3.7s with exit code 1]

Comment: I had no idea what are field names in your JSON, and just made them equal to the DB column names.